# Sending Data from Activity to Fragment using Bundle Giving Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bundle

Scenario is :

I Have a MainActivity(MainActivity.java) with pager making Fragment(MyFragment.java) in it.

I have one more activity called Main2Activity(Main2activity.java).

I want to send Data from Main2Activity to MyFragment.

Main2Activity.java:

```
  public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity{

  private String myString = "hello";

  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("path1", "Hey Brother");

            MyFragment frgmentObj = new MyFragment ();
            frgmentObj.setArguments(bundle);

   }
```

MyFragment.java :

```
   public class MyFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

String brother = getArguments().getString("path1");   // Here showing NPE
  return view;
}
}
```

But its giving me Null pointer exception

```
     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

please help me out
package is same
Thanks

Comment: Which activity run first ?

Comment: @Smatiz - MainActivity

Comment: @Smatiz - First - MyFragment.java , then Main2Activity , after that i need to send data from Main2Activity to Myfragment. Means i will come back to fragment.   So i think ur question's answere is Main2Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
String brother = bundle.getString("path1");
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Its fragment Not Activity , So i used                                                                                                             Bundle bundle = getArguments();
String brother = bundle.getString("path1");  But its not helping me out.

Comment: try doing this in `onCreate` rather then in`onCreateView`.

Comment: Its Fragment. Not an Activity.

Comment: you can do this in fragment my friend. and fragment has `onCreate` method if you know.